# Connect WordPress and React user sessions to give an access of WP user to React app in subdomain

Tags: wordpress, authentication, cookies, session-cookies

Not much experience with wordpress, but did a landing page on it (e.g. domain.com). At the same time, I have a react website in the app.domain.com subdomain. I'm trying to solve a problem in organizing the architecture of such a website.

In general, the task is that a user from wordpress, after logging in, could follow the link to app.domain.com and automatically log in there.

PS I see there http only cookie which appears after loggin in wordpress wordpress_logged_in_{hash} with a value includes user name and two coded lines like this

```
qwerty%7C1688925503%7CWkcXMDTAKGEBmSpcYwgKGOX8cAq1w1LBJ4gFD4WSKbt%7C76796e512
```